# Issue with Dice Command - Expected Number to be an Integer

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot with a dice command. When I type `,dice` it tells me `[user] please enter the amount of dice to roll` which works perfectly! But when I do want it to roll the dice, I type `,dice 1` and it gives me an error saying `Expected number to be an integer`.

Here is the code:

```js
const Random = require("random");

module.exports = {
    name: 'dice',
    description: '[DESCRIPTION]',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        const User = message.author.username
        
        if(!args[0]){
            message.channel.send(`${User} please enter the amount of dice to roll`);
        }
        else{
            let RandomNumber = Random.int((args[0]), (args[0] * 6))
            DiceEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle(`:game_die: ${User} rolled a:`)
            .setDescription(`${RandomNumber}`)
            .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(DiceEmbed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd try putting `parseInt(args[0])` around `args[0]`. It's posible that the `args[0]` is a `string` and the javascript function requires a number.

Comment: @BronislavRůžička That works! but is there a way for me to check if something is not a number? and also can u put that in the answer section so i can verify it works?

Comment: The [typeof statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is probably what you're looking for. For example `console.log(typeof args[0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's posible that the `args[0]` is a `string` and the javascript function requires a `number`. Therefore you probably need to convert the `string` to a `number`.

That that is can be done by putting `parseInt(args[0])` around `args[0]`.

Working example:

```js
const Random = require("random");

module.exports = {
    name: 'dice',
    description: '[DESCRIPTION]',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        const User = message.author.username

        if(!args[0]){
            message.channel.send(`${User} please enter the amount of dice to roll`);
        }
        else{
            const Args0AsInt = parseInt(args[0]);
            let RandomNumber = Random.int(Args0AsInt, (Args0AsInt * 6))
            DiceEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle(`:game_die: ${User} rolled a:`)
            .setDescription(`${RandomNumber}`)
            .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(DiceEmbed);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get the type of variable in javasript you should use the [`typeof` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). Just like this:

```
console.log( typeof args[0] );
```